# boost signal-slot generalisation

Tags: c++, boost, boost-signals

I am searching for a way to implement something like this, using boost

```
class GenBoost{
  boost::signal<void(void)> m_signal;
  std::function<void (bool)> m_function

  public:
    void setSignal(boost::signal<void(void)> sigArg)
    {
       m_signal = sigArg;
    }

    void setFunction(std::function<void (bool)> &functionArg)
    {
       m_function = functionArg;
       m_signal.connect(boost::bind(&GebBoost::onSignal,this,_1));

    }

    void onSignal(){
        //do something
    }
 };
```

How can this be achieved. signal copying is not possible!?

Comment: what should **this** be?

Comment: @itwasntpete - below code. I mean I tried to implement like above. But I couldn't.

Comment: make boost::signals pointers or shared pointers.

Comment: Is it really possible to make a signal which was already declared inside a class, for eg. `class A{
public:
    boost::signal<void(bool)> a_sig;
};` a shared_pointer? I know that possible ways of getting shared pointer is using `make_shared` and `ctor` of `shared_ptr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure of your intent, but assuming that `onSignal()` will not need to interact with `m_signal` (and that you only need one connection to `m_signal`), it appears that you can decouple `m_signal` from your class entirely. For example, if you really do not want the body of 'onSignal()' to be called until a 'm_function' has been set, you could do something like:

```
class GenBoost{
    std::function<void (bool)> m_function;
    boost::signals::scoped_conection m_connection;

  public:
    void setSignal(boost::signal<void(void)>& sigArg)
    {
        m_connection = sigArg.connect(boost::bind(&GebBoost::onSignal,this));
    }

    void setFunction(std::function<void (bool)> &functionArg)
    {
        m_function = functionArg;
    }

    void onSignal()
    {
        if ( m_function )
            do_work();
    }

    void do_work()
    {
        //do something
    }
};
```

Note that I stripped the last `_1` from `m_signal.connect(boost::bind(&GebBoost::onSignal,this,_1));` because the signal is declared as type `void(void)` so should be connected to a `void` callback. I also added the scoped_connection so that if the object of type `GenBoost` is destroyed before the signal it is connected to, it will automatically disconnect rather than allow the signal to retain an invalid pointer.

Alternatively, if you needed to retain a reference to the original signal, you could add back your original signal member, but as a pointer `boost::signal<void(void)>* m_signal;`. Then `setSignal` becomes:

```
void setSignal(boost::signal<void(void)>& sigArg)
{
    m_signal = &sigArg;
    m_connection = m_signal->connect(boost::bind(&GebBoost::onSignal,this));
}
```

I still recommend using the scoped connection and connecting in `setSignal` so that you ensure you only have one connection to one signal (If `setSignal` is called twice, the connection to the first signal is automatically disconnected). If you go the pointer route, you must externally ensure that the passed-in signal has a lifetime longer than the `GenBoost` object.

Comment: information about scoped_connection was useful. This was exactly I was  looking for. thanks.